# can I draw 3d surface plot using OpenGL in Android?

Tags: java, android, 3d, opengl-es

I receive real-time data from HC-05 Bluetooth and I want to show this data in a 3D surface chart, there were few libraries but I want to do it myself.
I can make Pyramids and Cubes but I am confused with the Surface chart. how can I draw shapes like the surface charts in OpenGL?

This is a picture of 3D surface chart :
https://www.nevron.com/NIMG.axd?i=Chart/ChartTypes/TriangulatedSurface/triangulated_surface_chart.png

Comment: What is a 3d surface plot. Show us a picture...

Comment: @YinOrYan I added the picture

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've done one of those for the Treasury yield curve. Since you say you can do cubes, than all you have to do is make a grid of them, right next to each other, with the top four points of each aligned with the X and Z axis, and rotate them all 45 degrees. Don't worry about the bottom parts of the cubes that are not visable, they will get z-sorted out of view. The hardest part will be the labels, so I suggest you prerender 20 textures, that is, 0 to 90, and 100 to 900, then slap them on the sides of white cubes. For the tray, just make a bunch of long grey cube 2 pixels thick...